# momentjs time comparison with timezone

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I am trying to compare two times:

Time A : A datetime which I know is in 'America/Chicago' timezone

Time B : A datetime for current time which I want to convert to 'America/Chicago' and compare to Time A.

I am doing this simple test and unable to understand why all the below give the same result:

```
moment('05/31/2018 03:25:00').tz('America/Chicago').diff(moment().tz('America/Phoenix'), 'minutes')
Result: 111

moment('05/31/2018 03:25:00').tz('America/Chicago').diff(moment().tz('America/Los_Angeles'), 'minutes')
Result: 110

moment('05/31/2018 03:25:00').tz('America/Chicago').diff(moment().tz('America/Chicago'), 'minutes')
Result: 110

moment('05/31/2018 03:25:00').diff(moment().tz('America/Chicago'), 'minutes')
Result: 110
```

Note: my system current time is 01:25 PST. So, I believe moment().tz('America/Los_Angeles') should mean 01:25 PST.

Please correct where I am going wrong. I am basically trying to compare a time in CST with current time in PST and find out what's the difference in minutes in real time.